# Can an Ethereum payment be split 90% & 10% between two wallets

Tags: ether

I'm setting up a site where my client wants all ETH donations to be split between him and his designer. Is it possible with the user only making the payment to one Wallet? And the payment being filtered upon arrival?

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely. You could something along the lines of this contract which receives the payment:

```
contract splitPayment {
   address recipient1 = 0x123; // @TODO: replace this!
   address recipient2 = 0x123; // @TODO: replace this!
   uint percentageRecipient1 = 90;
   uint percentageRecipient2 = 10;

  function() payable {
    recipient1.transfer(msg.value * percentageRecipient1 / 100);
    recipient2.transfer(msg.value * percentageRecipient2 / 100);
  }
}
```

That is a simple example, generally I'd favour pull over push payments, make the two recipients dynamic and updatable - in that case you need to think about who can do that (governance, separate owner?). Also beware that for tiny amounts the above contract would loose (burn!) funds due to rounding errors.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! I'm new to crypto, whereabouts in the source would I enter this?

Comment: there is no reason to lose any amount because of the rounding errors, get the first percentage and then substraction that from the total value.

Comment: As a public service announcement, this example contains anti-patterns, some of which are security risks.

Comment: @RobHitchens Could you provide some context? Very interested to hear more.

Comment: @Alacritas The fallback talks to msg.sender, recipient1 and recipient2 within the same transaction. If either recipient is malicious or even just a contract with no receive function (the default) then the transfer will be rejected. Since transactions are atomic, rejection by one is rejection by all. A recipient can DoS the other recipient as well as causing problems for the msg.sender that might naively assume that success is assured.

Comment: A general heuristic to keep in mind is a function should only talk to one "untrusted" contract at a time. msg.sender is one unless it's assured to be one of your own contracts or wallet, e.g. onlyOwner. Dito for the recipients. It's possible they are both trusted (owned/controlled) by the author in the intended use-case but nothing enforces that and anyone can use it. It isn't guaranteed to work and that can be surprising. Surprise is an anti-feature.

Comment: The "withdrawal pattern" is one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could deploy an instance of a [payment splitter contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment) that openzeppelin has, and then send funds to that address.

Alternatively, if you don't want to deploy your own contract, you can use [PaymentSplitter.io](https://paymentsplitter.io/) to spawn a cloneable instance of a payment splitter contract. Spawning a cloneable is also cheaper than deploying your own instance of a contract. Full disclaimer, I built the Web UI for it.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Civilian, SC Buergel and Rob Hitchens have said, the recommended way to do this is to use a [pull payment strategy](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/#favor-pull-over-push-for-external-calls).

First, you use Open Zeppelin's [PaymentSplitter contract](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment#PaymentSplitter) to send the payment to the contract with your desired recipients each receiving a certain number of shares.

In a separate transaction, the money is then **pulled** to the recipient's accounts using the [release](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/api/payment#PaymentSplitter-release-address-payable-) function.

The following snippet is taken from [Consensys' Smart Contract best practices](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices), the section titled [favor push over pull for external calls](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/recommendations/#favor-pull-over-push-for-external-calls):

> External calls can fail accidentally or deliberately. To minimize the damage caused by such failures, it is often better to isolate each external call into its own transaction that can be initiated by the recipient of the call. This is especially relevant for payments, where it is better to let users withdraw funds rather than push funds to them automatically. (This also reduces the chance of problems with the gas limit.) Avoid combining multiple ether transfers in a single transaction.